# Returning Array in Snowflake Stored procedure

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I have a stored procedure with return type as variant in snowflake. SP is written in JavaScript. Basically we are maintaining a array in SP and adding results and info just to maintain logs. The SP works fine when called from snowflake worksheets(UI) and returning

```
[
  "Using LOY DATABASE",
  "Using STAGE SCHEMA",
  "RUN ID - 20220517070653",
  "Truncating Table LOY.STAGE.MEMBER.",
  "Truncated Members Table.",
  "Data loaded to stage table.",
  "Swapped Stage table with Main Table.",
  "load_status - LOADED",
  "rows_loaded - 13175",
  "Procedure Successfully Completed.",
  "Members table count after loading : 13175"
]
```

But when the SP is called from a python script this array is converted to a string. I think it is because the array is of multi line and new line chars in present in array(multi lines) causing the result to convert as string.  we are getting result like this in the python script

```
[('[\n "Using LOY DATABASE",\n "Using STAGE SCHEMA",\n "RUN ID - 20220517145428",\n "Truncating Table LOY.STAGE.MEMBER.",\n "Truncated Members Table.", \n "Data loaded to stage table.",\n "Swapped Stage table with Main Table.",\n "load_status - LOADED",\n "rows_loaded - 13175",\n"Members table count after loading : 13175"]')]
```

I'm using literal_eval to convert the string to list in python currently. Is there a way to get the result as List in python script instead as string?

Comment: I don't think sending arrays through the standard or SQL Alchemy Python connectors is supported yet. https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy/issues/114. It's not supported yet on ODBC/JDBC either, so using the language on for the driver to parse the string to an array or JSON is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue is still the case. I solved this issue by using `ast.literal_eval()` function as follows;

```
df["column1"] = df["column1"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

Comment: I have used the same package to work around this limitation.

Comment: I switched to from_json() function to solve the issue.